# (Pages, iWork) Defining a space between some characters

Tags: macos, pages, spaces, iwork

Is it possible to make a "small" space after certain characters such as before "%". The space should be shorter than standard space, e.g., half of the default space.

An example:

[image]

I made the ***Half*** by making the "space" character to be a smaller font. However, I would like to define this space without changing any font size, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

For this, a NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE is probably a good choice. [Open the Character Picker](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-emoji-and-symbols-on-mac-mchlp1560/mac) and search for NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE. Since it's a space, it won't be really visible so you need to click into the results space, hoping to find it (see the greenish area in the screenshot). Then double-click to insert.

[image: Character Picker with Narrow No-Break Space]

Comment: I looked for the narrow no-break space and this [thread] (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5794296) should have solved it, but even after using the Hex Unicode keyboard, it somehow did not work - do you have any experiences with this solution, i.e. how to properly insert `option + 202F` on the Hex Unicode keyboard?

Comment: I haven't used the Hex Unicode keyboard yet, but I've attached a screenshot of the character picker. I've just tried this with Pages, the space was inserted correctly on double-clicking the greenish area.

Comment: To get the narrow no-break space (NNBS) character via the Hex keyboard, first add "Unicode Hex Input" via System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources and then activate it through the Input menu in the menu bar at the top of your desktop. Then hold down the "Alt ⌥" key and press in "2" "0" "2" "F" while continuing to hold down the  "Alt ⌥" key. On the other hand, I agree with @DarkDust that Character Viewer provides a more convenient way to get the NNBS.